# When i run this program it does not print the required output given by the called function for checking for balanced parenthesis?

Tags: c++, stack

i am currently working on a stack problem which checks for the balanced perenthesis in the input given to it. Maybe i am not able to get the output to be returned to the main function  .
here is the code that i wrote to solve the problem:
i am open to any recomendations to improve the code or any suggestions to fairly solve these type of questions .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

bool checkbalancedperanthesis(string exp){
    int n;
    n = exp.length();
    cout<<n;
    stack <char> S;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
       if (exp[i] == '[' || exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{')
       {
           S.push(exp[i]);
       }
       else if (exp[i] == ']' || exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}')
       {
           if (S.empty() || S.top() != exp[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                S.pop();
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    return (S.empty());

}

int main(){
    string exp;
    cout<<"Enter the expression you want to test for balanced experessions: ";
    cin>>exp;
    checkbalancedperanthesis(exp);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<exp;
}
```

Comment: `S.top() != exp[i]` What is this condition supposed to do? Will it ever be true?

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you iterate over the n-1 elements of the array.

Comment: You ignore the result of the function, btw.

Answer (score 0):

`S.top() != exp[i]` This condition won't work. It will never be true - you are comparing, for example, if `(` is equal to `)` which will never be true, and it will always return false. You should properly check if the brackets match.

Also, your loop runs till `n-2` which leads to not processing last bracket in the expression. It should be changed to `n-1`, by changing the condition to `i < n`.

Also, you don't seem to be doing any checking of the return value. You should check it appropriately in your code. For now, I just print the return value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool checkbalancedperanthesis(string exp) {
    int n = exp.length();
    //cout << n;
    stack <char> S;
    // CHANGE HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '[' || exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{')
        {
            S.push(exp[i]);
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ']' || exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}')
        {
            // CHANGE HERE
            char top_val = S.top();
            S.pop();
            if ((top_val == '(' && exp[i] == ')')
                || (top_val == '[' && exp[i] == ']')
                || (top_val == '{' && exp[i] == '}'))
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return S.empty();
}

int main() {
    string exp;
    cout << "Enter the expression you want to test for balanced experessions:\n";
    //cin>>exp;
    exp = "[[(){}]]";
    cout << exp << " " << checkbalancedperanthesis(exp) << endl;
    exp = "[[({}]]";
    cout << exp << " " << checkbalancedperanthesis(exp) << endl;
}
```